# Fundamental group of Alexandrov space.

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Is it true that the fundamental group of a compact finite dimensional Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below is finitely generated?

Comment: pp.9 of the article http://mural.maynoothuniversity.ie/10079/1/DW-Fundamental-1998.pdf says Yes, and that a result of Gromov  proves the group is generated by at most $(2.5)^{\dim(X)}$ generators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under these hypotheses the systole of $X$ is clearly bounded from below, and the usual comparison arguments would give an upper bound on the number of points in an $\epsilon$-net in $X$.  Then every loop can be discretized and the finite-generation follows.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask in addition whether the stronger statement is true: the minimal number of generators of the fundamental group is bounded above by a constant depending only on dimension, diameter, and a lower bound on curvature?

Comment: I am not sure.  You might want to try to run this by Anton Petrunin.

Comment: It is possible that this would follow from a 2017 publication by Sabourau where he provides a specific lower bound for the systole, modulo suitable hypotheses on $X$. @orbits